# Excel, Matching an Array in an index function

Tags: arrays, excel, filter, excel-formula, index-match

The goal here is to have a reverse index match function return the column/row header based off of a resultant array that was generated from a filter function.

Original dataset (=RANDARRAY(12,5,1,100,TRUE))
[image: Original dataset (=RANDARRAY(12,5,1,100,TRUE))]

Filtered Data Set =FILTER($E$48:$I$59,(($E$47:$I$47>=2019)*($E$47:$I$47<=2021)))
[image: Filtered Data Set =FILTER($E$48:$I$59,(($E$47:$I$47>=2019)*($E$47:$I$47<=2021)))]

The highlighted column headers in the second picture are what I am trying to have be generated dynamically by matching the array that was returned from the filter function to the original array.

I was thinking an Index function might work, possibly with an additional index in the match function in order to handle the 2D array I'm trying to search via, but I'm unable to get it to work.

I've also tried an iferror find function which does (via spill) return 1's for the expected column but I'm struggling with how I might use this to identify it as the column "2019" without the use of a helper column (which I'm trying to avoid).

IFERROR(FIND())
[image: IFERROR(FIND())]

Here's a clearer image of what I'm trying to achieve.
Looking for the year headers from the original data table, using the 1D array that was generated via the 'filer()' function to match the correct column.
This IndexMatch formula of course does not work, but it was a first attempt and illustrates the goal.
[image: Clearer Image of what I'm trying to do]

If anyone could offer some direction, advice, or guidance I'd be appreciative.

Thanks,

Comment: You current `FILTER()` formula should work what you expect. From which data you are getting `2019`, `2020` & `2021`?

Comment: Apologies if the pictures/my explanation there wasn't clear, the **2019**, **2020**, and **2021** highlighted in yellow are the values **I would like to see** based off of the values in the columns below each respective header, matched from the original data table. 

The **Filter()** function is indeed already working as expected, but I want the spilled array to have headers to mark where each column is from.

The headers highlighted there in yellow were added **manually** by me to illustrate the result I was looking to achieve.

Comment: Would it be a problem to filter columns while headers are included? =FILTER($E$47:$I$59,(($E$47:$I$47>=2019)*($E$47:$I$47<=2021))) or filter headers separately using same conditions =FILTER($E$47:$I$47,(($E$47:$I$47>=2019)*($E$47:$I$47<=2021))) ?

Comment: Are those values date values (years), table headers (text) or true numbers? All require different approach.

Comment: @P.b, in this current example they are integers, not table headers (the only way I know to dynamically change table headers is with VBA) or dates. In this exercise I would only be doing this with numbers or text strings.

Comment: @user11222393, That certainly would work, yes. However, I'm trying to figure out a way to do this by looking up the values from the array generated by the Filter function (if that's even possible) to determine the column the original header is in.

Comment: Then your formula should work. Aren't they the year presentation of a date value? In that case use `=FILTER($E$48:$I$59,(($E$47:$I$47>=date(2019,1,1)*($E$47:$I$47<date(2022,1,1))))` note the end date to be the next year and smaller than.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. You don't want to include the headers in the original formula, because the next formula refers to it, but you want the headers to be populated dynamically.
I think the better option would be to move the formula up one cell and include the header as suggested by user11222393 and in the next formula dont refer to `DROP(E61#,1)` instead of referring to `E62#`. 
Else explain the purpose of *not* including the headers in your filter in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

### Choose Columns Between Headers

```
=LET(data,E47:I59,start,2019,end,2021,
    h,TAKE(data,1),
FILTER(data,(h>=start)*(h<=end)))
```

[image]

- I'm not sure what made me do this.

```
=LET(data,E47:I59,start,2019,end,2021,
    h,TAKE(data,1),
    ms,XMATCH(start,h),
    me,XMATCH(end,h)+1,
CHOOSECOLS(data,SEQUENCE(,me-ms,ms)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly you're trying to lookup the values in a column of an array formula to entirely match a column in the main data.

As commented my advice would be to simply include the headers in the filter and when you need to refer to the numbers of the array excluding the headers, use `DROP(array,1)` so the first row is dropped.

But to answer your question:

You could do this using BYROW/MMULT by matching all single values in the column to match:

```
=BYCOL(E62#,LAMBDA(c,FILTER(E47:I47,MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ROWS(c),,0),N(c=E48:I59))=12)))
```

[image]

Or by using a double BYCOL/TEXTJOIN:

```
=LET(y,  E47:I47,
     cy, BYCOL(E48:I59,LAMBDA(c,TEXTJOIN(",",,c))),
BYCOL(E62#,LAMBDA(c,INDEX(y,XMATCH(TEXTJOIN(",",,c),cy)))))
```

[image]